# Random Forest error - Am I out of memory?

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm running the line:

```
 Frest <- randomForest(x = BFrame(,'Prediction'), y = BFrame[,which(colnames(BFrame) != 'Prediction')])
```

And it's giving the error:

> Error in randomForest(x = BFrame(, "Prediction"), y = BFrame[,
>   which(colnames(BFrame) !=  :    could not find function "BFrame"

`BFrame` is a `data.frame`

I'm extremely confused because I've used similar code before, and effectively. This time however, BFrame is large - 130000 observations of 18 variables. Is this error the result of me running out of memory does the source lie elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you meant `BFrame[,'Prediction']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser is reading `BFrame(, 'Prediction')` as a function to be called with no/missing first argument and second argument set to `'Prediction'`. I reasonably certain you mean the use brackets `[  ]` rather than parentheses `(  )` there:

```
BFrame[, 'Prediction']
```

Comment: Aw, cheers. I can't speak R past 12 at night apparently...